# Are these languages regular?

Tags: automata

$L_1 = \{0^k1^n \mid k \equiv n \bmod 3 \}$

This one I assume isn't since it's infinite

$L_2 = \{0^k1^{3k+2} \mid k>0 \}$

This one I assume also isn't regular because it relates on $k$ on both $0$ and $1$, and we can't store the amount of $0$'s we had so far

Am I right? Sorry if I'm mistaken, I'm new in the subject.
And how do I prove these to be right/wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You are right. The formal proof can be made by using the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. The language $L_1$ is regular. To show this, observe that
$$L_1 = \{0^{3k}1^{3n} \mid k, n \geqslant 0 \} \cup \{0^{3k+1}1^{3n+1} \mid k, n \geqslant 0 \} \cup \{0^{3k+2}1^{3n+2} \mid k, n \geqslant 0 \}$$
For the second question, use the pumping lemma to show that $L_2$ is not regular.

Comment: But the thing is that k is equal to n, so it's like saying basically.. 0^n1^n, is it not?

Comment: You mean for $L_2$? Yes, this is the same kind of proof. If you already know that $\{0^n1^n \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ is not regular, you could actually use this fact to prove that $L_2$ is not regular without using the pumping lemma.